# Load local plugin automatically in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

If I copy my plugin locally to QGIS I have to tick a box in repository to see/load it.

Is there any way to make this "checking" automatically, such that when I start QGIS it will be already loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you have to tweak windows registry.

If you are running windows and QGIS 2.x then QGIS settings are stored in registry under *"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\QGIS\QGIS2"*.

In particular, you can enable/disable plugins by setting true/false for the variable with a plugin name under *"...\QGIS2\PythonPlugins"*

Here's the command to run in windows command prompt to "uncheck" **autoTrace** plugin:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\QGIS\QGIS2\PythonPlugins" /v "autoTrace" /t REG_SZ /d false /f
```

You can also save it as a batch file and run it under the certain conditions.

[More on editing windows registry](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-edit-registry-using-command-prompt-windows-10)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Great answer.

Comment: It's quite obvious it's typo, but maybe you could remove this single quotation mark at the end.

Answer (score 9):

For a PyQGIS (hence, multi-platform) answer, you can create a `startup.py` file at `/home/USER/.qgis2/python/` (or `C:\Users\USER\.qgis2\python\` for Windows), and write this code inside:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
packageName = 'myPlugin' # Name of your plugin folder
QSettings().setValue( "PythonPlugins/" + packageName, True )
```

This will activate the plugin for you when QGIS starts.

Answer (score 1):

For QGIS3 you can use:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings
packageName = 'myPlugin'
QSettings().setValue( "PythonPlugins/" + packageName, True )
```